# User Mode Linux compile fails

Tags: compiling, linux-kernel, 64bit, user-mode-linux

I am trying to compile User Mode Linux on a 64 bit machine with `defconfig` and getting the following error.

```
arch/x86/um/user-offsets.c:1: sorry, unimplemented: code model "large" not supported yet
```

Any idea what this means?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From my shaky understanding: the compilation script is passing the [`-mcmodel=large`](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.3.0/gcc/i386-and-x86_002d64-Options.html) option to GCC. This option is only supported since GCC 4.3 ([or perhaps 4.4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11131998/from-which-version-of-gcc-does-mcmodel-large-work)). You seem to have an [older version](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.2.0/gcc/i386-and-x86_002d64-Options.html) where the option is recognized on the command line but not implemented under the hood.

This option produces an executable running in the [large model](http://eli.thegreenplace.net/2012/01/03/understanding-the-x64-code-models/), which consumes more memory for pointers but doesn't put any constraints on the address and size of code and data sections.
This [allows the kernel to run at any virtual address](http://wiki.osdev.org/Creating_a_64-bit_kernel). I think this is necessary for User-mode Linux because it has to coexist with the real kernel while itself pretending to be a kernel to user→kernel ABIs.

Comment: Thanks Gilles . Compilation is going ahead with GCC version 4.7.2. I had 4.1.2 in bu build server and that was causing the issue.